# Updating an S-57 base file with the associated update files

Tags: postgis, ogr2ogr, s-57

How do I use the update files in the S-57 format (.001, .002, ect.) to update the base file (.000)?
Alternatively, can I see if the base file has already been updated?

**Background**
My superior supplied me with a collection of S-57 files in a big folder structure which I'm supposed to enter into a PostGIS database. The collection is a large nautical chart that is split into many smaller areas. In the root of the folder structure there's a catalogue file (.031) which I don't know how to read.
Each of the smaller areas has it's own folder structure. Inside those folder structure there are folders numbering from 0 and up. Folder '0' contains the base file (.000) and the X folders contains the update files (.00X). I have no way of knowing if the update files have been applied already and I don't know how to apply them myself either.
I can import the base files into PostGIS without problem with ogr2ogr. I thought I could update the created tables with the `-update` option, but ogr2ogr cannot open the update files. So I would have to make sure that the base file is updated instead. Which I am currently at a loss for how to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... It didn't take long for me to find the answer on my own.

Ogr2ogr is apparently smart enough to step up in the folder structure to fetch the updates from the neighbouring folders. I found this out by removing the update files before importing and seeing that I got a different number of features.

**Edit:** I found more information on this. After importing you can see what update has been applied by checking the `dsid_updn` column in the `dsid` table.

Comment: Hi @Kapten-N - have you got any more info on how you achieved the import and updates? I have the same task and struggling to find anything.

Comment: @DaveC Sadly, I haven't worked on this for years now so it's anything but fresh in my memory. When I imported the updates were included in the provided folder structure and were automatically applied. The import itself was done with PostGIS. I don't know what else I can tell you.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to see that updates are applied when running ogr2ogr is to turn on the GDAL/OGR debug flag.  Set the CPL_DEBUG to ON and log the output CP_LOG. This was my way of finding out that OGR was applying all the update files in S57.
The S57 driver writes at lot what it is doing.